# Factorization systems in the category of toposes with geometric morphisms

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I have been thinking about geometric morphisms of topoi recently, and I am trying to organize some of what I know so far.

Right now my question is, what are some (weak, strong, etc.) factorization systems in the category of toposes with geometric morphisms?

I suspect that surjective maps and embeddings form such a system, and that monomorphisms and regular epimorphisms do as well.

What about connected morphisms and injective morphisms (where injective means that $f_*$ is faithful)?

Thanks!

Comment: The hyperconnected-localic and pure-entire factorisation systems are not mentioned below. There are further systems if we restrict attention to "nice" classes of geometric morphism, such as the 'skeletal' geometric morphisms (which admit a bunch of geometrically inspired factorisation systems) or the 'essential' geometric morphisms, which admit a factorisation relying on the extra adjoint functor they carry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a broad question, but I think much of what you are looking for is contained in section VII.4 of *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by Mac Lane and Moerdijk. That is the section *Embeddings and Surjections* in the chapter *Geometric Morphisms*, so you can guess what it is about ;)

Briefly, we have the following results (numbering refers to the aforementioned book).

> **Definition.** A geometric morphism $f: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$ is a(n)
>
> - *surjection* if the inverse image functor $f^*$ is faithful;
> - *embedding* if the direct image functor $f_*$ is full and faithfull.

The condition for the embedding is equivalent to saying that the counit of the adjunction is an isomorphism. An example of an embedding is the sheafification functor $a: \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}} \to \operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}, J)$. Together with the inclusion functor $i: \operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}, J) \to \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}$, they form a geometric morphism $a \dashv i$ and the counit is an isomorphism (which is saying that taking the sheafification of a sheaf does nothing). In fact, geometric embeddings correspond to topologies on the domain of the embedding (corollary VII.4.7).

In fact, that is a corollary to the following factorisation theorem.

> **Theorem (VII.4.6).** Let $f: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$ be a geometric morphism. Then there exists a topology $j$ on $\mathcal{E}$, such that $f$ factors through the geometric embedding $i: \operatorname{Sh}_j(\mathcal{E}) \to \mathcal{E}$ by a geometric surjection $p$.

There is also a uniqueness statement. However, the category of toposes with geometric embeddings should really be considered as a 2-category. Which loosely means that we should considering commuting diagrams up to natural isomorphism.

> **Theorem (VII.4.8, weakened).** Suppose $\mathcal{F} \xrightarrow{p} \mathcal{A} \xrightarrow{u} \mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F} \xrightarrow{q} \mathcal{B} \xrightarrow{v} \mathcal{E}$ are two factorisations of $f: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$, in the sense that the relevant triangles commute up to isomorphism. If both are a geometric surjection follows by a geometric embedding, then there is an equivalence $g: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ making everything commute (up to natural isomorphism).

I wrote "weakened", because the actual theorem (in the book) is a lot stronger. It allows us to compare any two factorisations of $f$ where $p$ is a surjection and $v$ is an embedding. So this $g$ exists in those cases, but it is not always an equivalence for arbitrary factorisations.